# how to filter section wise row in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm new in iOS and creating a demo app on basis of JSON response.

my query is I don't know how to write and filter row data section wise to show on tableview.

category.json [file]

```
{
    "category": [
        {
            "vName": "Section 0",
            "skill": [
                {
                    "vName": "Section 0 Row 1",
                },
                {
                    "vName": "Section 0 Row 2",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "vName": "Section 1",
            "skill": [
                {
                    "vName": "Section 1 Row 1",
                },
                {
                    "vName": "Section 1 Row 2",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "vName": "Section 2",
            "skill": [
                {
                    "vName": "Section 2 Row 1",
                },
                {
                    "vName": "Section 2 Row 2",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "vName": "Section 3",
            "skill": [
                {
                    "vName": "Section 3 Row 1",
                },
                {
                    "vName": "Section 3 Row 2",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Response.Swift [file]

```
//
//  Response.swift
//  SectionTableSearchDemo
//

import Foundation
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let category: [Category]
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let vName: String
    let skill: [Skill]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case vName,skill
    }
}

struct Skill: Codable {
    let vName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case vName
    }
}
```

#SectionTableviewController.swift [file]

```
//
//  SectionTableViewController.swift
//  SectionTableSearchDemo
//

import UIKit


class SectionTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var cat : Welcome?
    var searchController : UISearchController!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        parseJSON()
        searchControllerSetup()
    }

     private func searchControllerSetup(){
        
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
    
    // i don't know how to implement and show only skills when search
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
    }
    
    private func parseJSON(){
        
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "category", ofType: "json")else{
            return
        }
       
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            cat = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
            if let result = cat {
                print(result)
            }
        } catch  {
            print("Error is \(error)")
        }
        
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return  (cat?.category.count)!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if let cat = cat {
            return cat.category[section].skill.count
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let text = cat?.category[indexPath.section].skill[indexPath.row].vName
        cell.textLabel?.text = text

        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let titleText = cat?.category[section].vName
        return titleText
    }
    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

and my image of [what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfGfF.png)

please help me to figure out

Thank you

Comment: Once again, like in your deleted question, this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857221/how-to-search-data-in-tableview/56857544#56857544

Comment: I would help myself by running a search and see how other people do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search data inside the model you can use the Filter function.
Same way as you are showing data inside tableview cell. You can search using the filter function and show data inside based on the search flag.

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        guard let searchText = searchText, !searchText.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        searchData = cat?.category.map({
                        $0.skill.filter({$0.vName == searchText})
                           }).filter({ $0.count > 0 })

        searching = true
        self.searchedSkillsResults = searchData
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

//Check here if your search is true and show skills array else original array results with search false.

reference link: [how to search data from model in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468923/how-to-search-data-from-model-in-swift)

//below link help you to search within nested array.
[Swift Filter Nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595393/swift-filter-nested-array/39595725)

My sample code which is working:

```
import Foundation
struct Welcome: Codable {
   let category: [Category]
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let vName: String
    let skill: [Skill]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case vName,skill
    }
}

struct Skill: Codable {
    let vName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

         case vName
    }
 }

 var cat : Welcome?

 private func parseJSON(){

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "category", ofType: 
        "json")else{
        return
    }

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    print(url)

    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        cat = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
        if let result = cat {
             print(result)
        }
    } catch  {
        print("Error is \(error)")
    }
}

parseJSON()
//print(cat)

let searchText = "Section 0 Row 1"
let result = cat?.category.map({
   $0.skill.filter({$0.vName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
}).filter({ $0.count > 0 })

//output = Optional([[Skill(vName: "Section 0 Row 1")]])
```

Comment: ``` 
searchData = cat?.category.map({
                        $0.skill.filter({$0.vName == searchText})
                           }).filter({ $0.count > 0 })
print(searchData)
```
gives output as [], I have take searchData as 
var searchData : [[Skill]]?

Comment: use contains or lowercased the vName and searchText to search it will give result.

Comment: Although (and unfortunately) it’s being suggested in many tutorials you should prefer [`localizedCaseInsensitiveContains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412098-localizedcaseinsensitivecontains) over calling `lowercased()` continuously.

Comment: yes, you can use that as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @msusare , 
your code is working but one issue there, in searchBar method ** searchData** shows total result count
but when I use same ** searchData* in tableview numberOfsections method , it shows zero (0) count

any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following.

Add two variables like below.

```
var filteredProducts = [Category]()
var products: [Category] = []
```

and initialize product variable

```
///......
let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
cat = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)

products = cat.category // add this line
```

now modify table view data sources like the following

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
             return filteredProducts.count
        }
        return products.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
             return filteredProducts[section].skill.count
        }else{
            return products[section].skill.count
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let product: Category
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            product = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            product = products[indexPath.row]
        }

        let text = product.skill[indexPath.row].vName
        cell.textLabel?.text = text

        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let product: Category
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            product = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            product = products[indexPath.row]
        }
        let titleText = product[section].vName
        return titleText
    }
```

and then create a function to filter your data

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
        filteredProducts = products.filter({( product : Category) -> Bool in
            return product.title!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        yourTableView.reloadData() // reload your table view
}
```

call `filterContentForSearchText()`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
     filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!)
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
     filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
```

Comment: is your code search for section name?
I want search for row

Comment: @Pinal  I just shared a way how you can solve your problem. You have to implement your own logic here **` filteredProducts = products.filter({( product : Category) -> Bool in
            return product.title!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })`**